# How do I sharpen a knife in the wild?

Tags: knives, camping

I went camping near a river the other day, and realized that my trusty pocketknife was pretty dull. It made my camping experience not too fun. Is there any way to get a knife reasonably sharp without real tools (e.g. dedicated stone, or sharpening steel)? I'm in the wilderness, and don't have these tools with me, nor access to a store where I could buy them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I saw a Youtube video on this a while back*....can't find it now, but I'll post whatever I remember.

Basically, the way knife-sharpening works is that you shave off little bits of metal, in order to make the edge of your knife V-shaped. Ideally, you'd use a steel or a specialized stone for this, but if you don't have any, here are some things you could use instead:

- **Top of a car window**
- **Bottom of a ceramic mug** (*see also [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5479413/sharpen-your-kitchen-knife-on-a-coffee-mug) by [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/)*)
- You might use **cement**, but only for about two seconds, and only in place of a really coarse stone (=for beginning stage sharpening)
- If you're camping, you might use a straight metal **tent-peg** in place of a steel (my suggestion, not from the video)
- If you're near a river, **flat river stones** might help you (but try to find a big one, for ease-of-use)
- Also suggested by Crazy Russian Hacker, if I remember correctly, is to use a **leather belt as a [strop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razor_strop)**, basically running the knife backwards over the leather belt, to give it a nicer finish. This may not help you if your knife is severely out of shape, but it could work to make an almost-good knife perfect. I've done this myself when I wanted to show my knife (pictured in my gravatar) to a professional *shochet*, and although I had my stones with me, I didn't have time to soak them and sharpen my knife properly. I just took off my belt, ran the knife over it several times, and the knife *really* improved a lot. Kudos to Jon for reminding me of this hack :)

I would suggest that you do ***NOT***

- Use **another knife**, because you have a good chance of ruining at least one of your knives, if not both of them.

---

**IIRC, it's by a guy who calls himself "Crazy Russian Hacker," but I can't find that video now*

Comment: Polishing a blade also sharpens it. Barbers use a leather strap to keep a straight edge sharp. If you are wearing a leather belt it can be used to polish the edge.

Comment: @Jon, that sounds interesting, was there a reason you didn't make that an answer?  I'd like to hear a bit more about how to do that.

Comment: @Jon I've actually done that :) ....I wanted to show my knife to someone, and didn't have my stones with me. IIRC that was also mentioned in the video. I think I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @NelsonWright Yes there was a definite reason, I was being lazy. Thought it would be OK as a supplement to the best accepted answer that stood on its on merits.

Comment: @NelsonWright (and Jon) what do you think of the answer now?

Comment: @NelsonWright Oh yes love it, I was typing my last comment and going to add I thought about editing it into your post, but thought that presumptuous, but would not mind at all if OP added it.

Comment: @Jon If I would have seen the suggested edit, I would have approved; though I can't promise that other reviewers would have done the same.

Comment: @Shokhet Looks good! I've voted for that.  Jon:  Hah, well, we've all been there.  Thanks for sharing though!

Comment: Still can't find that video. Hm...

Answer (score 6):

You mentioned that you're near a river and have a pocket knife.

- Go to the river and find a flat smooth stone.
- Pour cooking oil or water on the stone for a lubricant.  Oil is preferable but water works in a pinch.
- Put the knife blade flat on the stone then raise it to a 10 to 15 degree angle.
- Sharpen the first side of the blade by pushing the blade away from you along the stone with moderate pressure about 6-12 times.
- Sharpen the other side of the blade.
- Now sharpen both sides, one side each pass.